# Jsp & stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsp, stored-procedures

I issue SP from Jsp, code is here:

```
sql = "EXEC REP_INVOICES ?,?";   
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = cox.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
ps.setInt(1, cycle);
ps.setInt(2, zone);
ps.execute();
```

Procedure runs several seconds and fills a table. I want to know when it is over to make outputs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has been ages since I did java.

However, there is JDBC and SQL libraries.

I think you are using the first.  Here is a link to execute().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

I guess the main question is this statement modal?  After the execute() does the java wait until the call is finished?  I think so.

Have the stored procedure return a value.  Check it.  After that, you whole table should be populated.

The only other alternative is to do paging.  Load only a few records in the table at a time.  Should produce quicker response times.

Here is the definition from the manual on return values and how to get them from a SPROC call.

```
execute
boolean execute()
  Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL  
  statement. Some prepared statements return multiple results; the execute method handles these 
  complex statements as well as the simpler form of statements handled by the methods 
  executeQuery and executeUpdate. 

The execute method returns a boolean to indicate the form of the first result. You must call 
either the method getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result; you must call 
getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).
```